Dynamic nginx Configuration: Proxy to Backend based on Host of Frontend
I am looking for an nginx configuration that routes specific requests from my frontend to my backend.
Frontend URL: https://my-app-ui-[stage].org
Backend  URL: https://my-app-[stage].org
[stage] being a suffix that changes for our different stage environments. On production, this part is missing entirely.
All requests with a path beginning mit /api should be routed to the backend.
The nginx configuration should be dynamic, so that I can use the same on all stages.
I have been looking into nginx reverse proxy settings: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/
But I could not figure out, how to use the current host name to derive the backend URL.

From what I've read, this is not possible.
The location is meant to be relative to the host and does not allow to filter based on the host name.
I ended up using multiple server sections with their own specific proxy settings, whereas -d stands for development in our case.
server {
    server_name  "~^.*my-app-ui-d.*$";

    location /api {
        proxy_pass https://my-app-d.org;
    }
}

